# function overloading with a lot of arguments

Tags: c++, overloading

Say I have this constructor in C++:

```
 A::A( std::string const& name,
       std::string const& type,
       std::vector<B> const& b_vec,
       bool unique )
     : _name(name), _type(type), _b_vec(b_vec), _unique(unique)
     { };
```

I would like to overload this constructor for the case where the arguments are rvalues (I want to use move semantics there).

```
 A::A( std::string && name,
       std::string && type,
       std::vector<B> && b_vec,
       bool unique )
     : _name(name), _type(type), _b_vec(b_vec), _unique(unique)
     { };
```

The above one works fine when all of the arguments are rvalues, but suppose if only some of them are is in the next example:

```
 // create some lvalues somehow
 std::string name   = "stack overflow";
 std::vector<B> vec = { ... }; // implementation of B's constructot is not important

 // call a mixed constructor
 A new_A_instance(name, "cool-website", vec, true);
```

it is to my understanding that since 'const&' cannot bind to '&&' but '&&' can bind to 'const&' the first (non-move) constructor would be used.

This seems sub-optimal, since two of the four arguments could be moved (because they are rvalue) instead of being copied (as is the case in the first constructor).

So I could overload the operator for this specific case, but one could easily image a case where other arguments are rvalue and others are agin lvalue. Should I overload the constructor for each of these cases? This would combinatorily lead to very much overloads as the number of arguments increases...

I kind-of *feel* there is a better solution (perhaps using templates, but my template knowledge is shamefully low).

Note: this problem isn't tied to overloading pass-by-ref functions to move functions per-se, but I found this a good example (especially since the overloads don't *feel* very different). Also note that I just used constructors as an example, but the overloaded function can be anything.

Comment: An rvalue bool, as well as a `const bool`, are utterly pointless.

Comment: @Kerrek: I agree. Don't know why I put them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass by value, this is what move semantics are for:

```
 A::A(std::string name, std::string type, std::vector<B> b_vec, bool unique )
   : _name(std::move(name)), _type(std::move(type)), _b_vec(std::move(b_vec)),
     _unique(unique)
 { };
```

This has the expected behaviour in every case. Passing a temporary by value allows the compiler to perform *copy elision*, which it pretty much always does.

Note that in your second code, copies are made, since you don't use `std::move`. Please realize that when you write

```
void foo(bar&& x)
{
    ...
}
```

then in the body of `foo`, `x` is a **lvalue**. Objects with names are *always* lvalues. Inside this body, you must use `std::move(x)` if you intend to pass `x` as a rvalue.

Comment: Actually, the edit isn't quite correct. `x` is indeed always a `bar&&`. But it's not an rvalue! Note that `bar&&` means "rvalue *reference*", and not "rvalue".

Comment: so this code would outperform pass-by-ref code whilst still retaining constness of the passed objects?

Comment: @romeovs: yes. Pass by value whenever you can.

Comment: @Alexandre C. This doesn't have the expected behaviour of not creating copies of arguments that could be moved.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I edited the wording. It helps to consider `x` as having type `bar&` though.

Comment: @AlexandreC. wow! In class I was always taught to pass-by-value as much as I could. Of course that was before C++11 (or even C++0x).

Comment: @SegFault: If you want a lvalue to be moved, you must ask explicitly for it in any case. For temporaries, copy elision does the job here.

Comment: @SegFault exaclty, that is what I want to achieve

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I know what you intended, but it's simply not correct. It's no better than claiming that an int-reference is the same as an int. It's not... :-( In other words, an rvalue reference can *bind* to an rvalue, but it is not itself an rvalue. It's just a reference.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are obviously right. Anyway I simplified the wording, I believe it is correct now.

Comment: @AlexandreC. could you elaborate on that in you answer? Also, is this 'always pass-by-val' new to C++11 then or was my teacher very wrong?

Comment: @romeovs: It's something which always existed in fact. See http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ for instance.

Comment: @AlexandreC: Understood, instead of explicitly moving all the time you let the compiler do the optimisation.

Comment: Ok, but as to what height will the compiler optimize? If I make a vector of `A`s will it use `A`'s move constructor when I move the vector?

Comment: @romeovs: If the vector is a temporary, then it will be created at the call site, and then moved into your object. If it is a lvalue and you decide to move it with `std::move`, then two moves will be performed.

Comment: OK, another nitpick. `x` is *not* an object. References are never objects. `x` is a variable and a reference, but not an object. *Evaluating the expression `x`*, however, gives an lvalue of type `bar`.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Not quite what I meant. There are a bunch of articles on move semantics around that tell one to implement a move constructor and assignment operator so tha the std library can make use of them. But if what you say is correct (which I do believe), there should be no need to do so, since copy elision always makes sure no unnecessary copy is made.

Comment: @KerrekSB: This is why I find it simpler to say that `x` behaves as if it has been declared `foo&` :) When I say `x` is a lvalue, `x` should be understood as the expression `x`, not the variable `x` :D.

Comment: @romeovs: Good one. Copy constructors must take their argument by reference. If they took it by value, and for some reason copy elision cannot take place, the how do you copy the object ? The point is that when passing by value, then either 1) copy is elided 2) copy constructor is called 3) move constructor is called. Point 1) can involve before elision the creation of an object, via any constructor.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Ah! finally evertything comes together. So I do need to define the move constructor, and trust on copy elision to do the rest of the work.. sweet. That article you gave me is super-awesome, by the way!

Comment: Exactly. The coding gets simpler, and the program runs faster :)